# I get an infinite loop and i am not sure why or how to fix it

Tags: c++

```
ifstream olympicsStream;
        olympicsStream.open("olycs105.txt");
```

> This is where the file is opened

```
        olympicsStream >> firstcountry; // string variable for countries
        while (firstcountry!="END_OF_FILE")//
```

> Can't figure out what to put here for condition

```
        {

            cout << firstcountry << endl;
            olympicsStream >> a;
            cout << a << endl;

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                olympicsStream >> namelast[i];
                olympicsStream >> namefirst[i];
                olympicsStream >> b[i];
                olympicsStream >> c[i];
                olympicsStream >> d[i];
                getline(olympicsStream, Asport[i]);
            }


            cout << namelast[i - 1] << endl;
            cout << namefirst[i - 1] << endl;
            cout << b[i - 1] << endl;
            cout << c[i - 1] << endl;
            cout << d[i - 1] << endl;
            cout << Asport[i - 1];
        }
```

> loops 5 lines needed but the same line infinitely instead of reading through the rest of the file

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could put your text file here. If it's too large then maybe put a part of it.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to update the variable 'firstcountry' at the end of while loop.

Just add `olympicsStream >> firstcountry;` before closing the while loop and your code should run fine

Assuming the last word in the file is "END_OF_FILE"